# Unlist (flatten lists) row by row in a data frame using R

Tags: r

I have a list of tweets in a data.frame and I can extract lists of hashtags from them using

```
> rpg.twitter.df$hashtags <-
  regmatches(rpg.twitter.df$text,gregexpr("#(\\d|\\w)+",rpg.twitter.df$text))
```

It ends up with one list for each row. Now, I want to flatten each list in comma-separated strings (one for each row)

I tried this:

```
do.call("paste", c(rpg.twitter.df$hashtags, sep=", "))
```

but it doesn't work as it ends up with one huge vector. Same if i enclose `regmatches` with `unlist(..., recursive=FALSE)`

any idea on how to solve it?

Some data for a reproducible example:

```
rpg.twitter.df <- data.frame(text=rbind("World of Warcrack: http://t.co/3MNRpArnGw #wow #WorldOfWarcraft #warcraft #mmorpg #rpg #RPGChat #gaming #pcgaming #online @WoW_en @NewsWoW", "@ashleythedragon join my journey in Tweeria http://t.co/CFKDLA3ASE #rpg", "How to use of #RPG  for motivation  #timeboxing  http://t.co/mwwN5xErHx"))
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example? Have you tried `do.call("c", ...)` or `do.call("rbind", ...)`?

Comment: yep, no way. Meanwhile I've added some data for reproducing

Comment: Be careful when you say "list". Half of the time, you mean "vector".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
sapply(rpg.twitter.df$hashtags, paste, collapse = ",")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this :

```
 toString(rpg.twitter.df$hashtags)
```